# Phrase/word for "human to god" love / idolatry?

Tags: words, slang, colloquial-language, culture, word-requests

A Korean friend used a word that I believe was a Japanese loan word, that he said meant a "human to god" kind of love - an 'inferior' being loving or idolizing a 'superior' one. It wasn't a phrase but just one word... Does this sound familiar or should I ask around on a Korean site?

Comment: Probably no problem here (aside from that we don't have Korean SE site yet...), but are you sure what you need is "colloquial language" or "slang", as your tags suggest?

Comment: There is a word that means what you said and it seems to be used in Korean as well, but it is a Sino loanword.

Comment: @l'électeur So are you going to enlighten us to what this particular word is (even if it's a Sino loanword)?

Comment: Would "uyamau" come close?

Answer (score 2):

Gleaning from the comments that this might be a term that originally came from Chinese, one guess would be [崇拝【すうはい】](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B4%87%E6%8B%9D), often glossed as *"worship"* but with overtones of *"admiration, adoration"*.  The traditional form of these kanji is [崇拜](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B4%87%E6%8B%9C), the form still used in written Chinese, with readings of *chóngbài* (Mandarin), *sung<sup>4</sup> baai<sup>3</sup>* (Cantonese), *chhùng-pai* (Hakka), and *chông-pài* (Min Nan).  The term is also used in Korean, as [숭배]{sungbae}.